# Can someone explain to me whats the function of this function

Tags: javascript

i can understand whats going on in this code . can someone explain to me whats going on

ive tried to analyze each function but still i dont understand

```
var animatepage = function() {
    var elems;
    var windowHeight;

    function init() {
        elems = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden");
        windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        addEventHandlers()
        checkPosition()
    }

    function addEventHandlers() {
       window.addEventListener('scroll', checkPosition);
       window.addEventListener('resize', init)
    }

    function checkPosition() {
        for(var i=0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            var positionTop = elems[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            if ((positionTop-windowHeight) <= 0) {
                elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace(
                    'hidden',
                    'fade-in-element'
                );
            };

        };
    };
    return {
        init: init
    };
};
animatepage().init();
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: It's deciding whether to show certain elements or not on resizing the window or scrolling the page. It basically makes elements fade in assuming the name 'fade-in-element'.

Comment: Looks like code that is meant to fade in elements when scrolled into view. As it stands, it is horrible code though, because it adds uncountable listeners to the resize and scroll event every time resize triggers.

Comment: how it works sir

Comment: StackOverflow is not a teaching portal. You can ask *explicit* questions about specific programming problems, but asking "how does all this work and what does it do" (evenmoreso on quite basic stuff) is considered off-topic on SO. See what is considered on-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose is to add the CSS class "fade-in-element" when elements become visible in the page.

- `init()` finds all the elements that have the CSS class "hidden".
- `addEventHandlers()` makes sure that if the user scrolls or resizes their window that we check if any new elements are visible
- `checkPosition()` then finds all elements that are currently visible and gives them the CSS class "fade-in-element". That class will probably include some CSS transitions to make the element slowly fade in.

Comment: thus the init() can be change to somethingFunction() ?

Comment: @WayanDanyaelEco you could name `init` whatever you want, as long as you're consistent about it. If you rename the function, you need to rename anything that also references it to use the correct name.

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you sir so much . i was just confuse if the init() is built-in function